# Ublaboo/Datagrid - InlineAdd row is hidden

Tags: php, datagrid, nette

after update to Ublaboo/Datagrid v6.2, PHP 7.3 and Nette 3.0, in all pages (grids) where I used inlineAdd feature, this feature stopped working. I figured out, that after click on Add button, row with inlineAdd is added into table but with class **datagrid-row-inline-add-hidden**, which is making this row hidden.

I tried to download [Ublaboo/Datagrid Playground](https://examples.planette.io/contributte/datagrid/add) project from [GIT](https://github.com/planette/playground/tree/master/contributte-datagrid) and paste my code there. I also tried to install there my bower.json to be sure, that I have the same CSS and JS. But in the playground project that I edited is everything working fine with same code as I have in my project.

Can anyone give me some advice where to look for bugs, please?

Thank you.

Comment: I believe that you don't get answer here. Try create issue directly here: https://github.com/contributte/datagrid/issues